# Discriminator on referenced id

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

My title might not be the best description, but it's best I could come up with.

I have 4 entities; Page, PageElement, Image and an entity called TextWithImage. Page holds pageElements (array of PageElement entities). Those pageElements can be of numerous types, but for now I have only one called TextWithImage that's holding additional data to the data the PageElement entity holds.

The PageElement can be included on numerous pages and so, I have a ManyToMany in the PageElement.orm.yml. The TextWithImage has a manyToOne to reference to Image.

(More information: Another Entity ImageGallery might have a manyToMany relationship with the Image entity, while TextOnly shouldn't have any reference to the Image entity.)

I want to be able to get the Page and retrieve the PageElements with all their "attributes". So let's say I request to get a Page with only one TextWithImage type of PageElement, I want to return the following.

```
Page -> pageElements = array (
    [0] => TextWithImage -> image = Image -> filename = "image.png"
                                          -> alt = "An image!"
                         -> text  = "There's an image too!"
)
```

All seems simple enough, but I need doctrine to understand that this PageElement is a TextWithImage type. Can I do this with a DiscriminatorColumn, say (rough sketch);

```
Table: pageelement
id | attributes | discr | TextWithImageId

Table: textwithimage
id | attributes
```

Keep in mind that I'll have more than just one type of PageElement, not only TextWithImage.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. These are the doctrine YML files. You can generate all entities with `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity`. *Make sure that the PageTextImageElement class extends the PageElement class.*

**Page.orm.yml**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Page:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repositories\PageRepository
    manyToMany:
        pageElements:
            targetEntity: PageElement
            cascade: ["all"]
            joinTable:
                name: null
                joinColumns:
                    page_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                        onDelete: CASCADE
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    page_element_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                        unique: true
                        onDelete: CASCADE
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: '255'
            unique: true
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**PageElement.orm.yml**

```
AppBundle\Entity\PageElement:
    type: entity
    inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: discr
        type: string
    discriminatorMap:
        pageTextImageElement: PageTextImageElement
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repositories\PageElementRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        sortOrder:
            type: integer
        attributes:
            type: array
            nullable: true
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**PageTextImageElement.orm.yml**

```
AppBundle\Entity\PageTextImageElement:
    type: entity
    table: null
    oneToOne:
        image:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Image
            joinColumn:
                name: imageId
                referencedColumnName: id
    fields:
        passage:
            type: string
            length: '255'
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Image.orm.yml**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Image:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repositories\ImageRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: '255'
            unique: true
        description:
            type: string
            length: '255'
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```